# How to get the data from 3 tables with one to many relation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I have table named **SCORES**, then inside has foreign key named subject_id which relationship is one to many from table named **SUBJECTS** then inside table **SUBJECTS** has foreign key also named user_id which relationship is one to many from table named **USERS**, now I was able to show the list of subject from **SCORES** table now how to get the username who's subject_id is equal to user_id.

**Controller:**

```
$scores = Score::with('lead','subject')->where('lead_id','=',$id)->get();

$subjects=Subject::with('user')->get();
```

**View**

```
<tr> 
  @foreach($scores as $score)
     <th><font size="1">&nbsp;</font></th> 
  @endforeach 
</tr>

<tr>
  @foreach($scores as $score)
 <td>
   <font size="1">{{$score->subject->subject_name}}</font>
  @endforeach 
 </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: in your scores table do you have `user_id` and `subject_id` ?

Comment: i only have subject id in my score table sir

Comment: then, how could you know, which score is belongs to which user ?

Comment: score to subject not a problem its subject to user i want  to get the user of the subject..

Comment: yes, thats why you need a `user_id` field in score table then you can create a `belongsTo` relation in `Score` model and fetch the user

Comment: i cannot pull the user base on the subject id?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176987/discussion-between-rkj-and-grace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From chat discussion it found that you have `belongsTo` relation between `Subject` and `User` model. You are using the `subject_id` in your scores table and your `Score` model has `belongsTo` relation to `Subject` Model. So, yes you can fetch the user details like this

```
{{$score->subject->user->name}}
```

Comment: thank you sir, by the way can i have follow up question? just to get idea on how to deal with issue related to this topic..

Comment: sure, whats that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `belongTo` relationship in score model.

```
public function user(){
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'subject_id ');
}
```

Now you can get user name something like this.

```
$scores = Score::with('lead','subject')->with('user')->where('lead_id','=',$id)->get();
```

Comment: Sir, Score table only has subject id , i will get relation error if i use with('user')

Comment: could you please show database structure or migration

Answer (score 0):

## Index.php

```
      $posts = Posts::read_all();

      foreach ( $posts as $post )
 {
         echo $post->post_name ."<br>";
          echo $post->post_text ."<br>";

$categories_array = Posts::get_cats_by_post_id($post->id);

foreach ($categories_array as $category)
{
    echo "&bull;". $category->category_name ."<br>";
}
```

}

## Post Class

public static function get_cats_by_post_id($id)
{
    $db = new Database();

```
$sql = "SELECT  cats_to_posts.cats_id
        FROM    cats_to_posts
        WHERE   cats_to_posts.post_id = {$id}";

$result = $db->exe_query($sql);

$cat_id_array = array(); // stores array of category ids that match post ids

while ( $record = $result->fetch_object() )
{
    $cat_id_array[] = $record;
}

$cat_name_array = array(); // stores array of category names that match category ids
foreach($cat_id_array as $cat_id)
{
    $new_sql = "SELECT  category_name
                FROM    categories
                WHERE   id = ". $cat_id->cats_id;

    $new_result = $db->exe_query($new_sql);

    while ( $new_record = $new_result->fetch_object() )
    {
        $cat_name_array[] = $new_record;
    }

}

return $cat_name_array;
```

}

**Try this**
Hope  so this will work.

Comment: Please don't post the answer something like this because of this could not be answered.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your view